# Is there a varargs null check function in Java or Apache Commons?

Tags: java, validation, null, variadic-functions

I've got four variables and I want to check if any one of them is null. I can do

```
if (null == a || null == b || null == c || null == d) {
    ...
}
```

but what I really want is

```
if (anyNull(a, b, c, d)) {
    ...
}
```

but I don't want to write it myself. Does this function exist in any common Java library? I checked Commons Lang and didn't see it. It should use varargs to take any number of arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best you can do with the Java library is, I think:

```
if (asList(a, b, c, d).contains(null)) {
```

Comment: With a static import of java.util.Arrays.asList, I presume?

Comment: close to literate programming

Comment: A little slower, too, one would guess, but no external libraries and no figuring out where to put the anyNull method.

Comment: It can also be used as: if (List.of(a, b, c, d).contains(null)).
But be aware that an instance of ImmutableCollections will be created

Comment: @DiegoSouza And the array is copied, but the big problem is `List.of(a, b, c, d).contains(null)` will never retain false - it will NPE.

Answer (score 19):

I don't know if it's in commons, but it takes about ten seconds to write:

```
public static boolean anyNull(Object... objs) {
    for (Object obj : objs)
        if (obj == null)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, I just did some scouting around and found a couple of anyNull methods, but they seem to predate varargs.

Comment: I tried searching Google Code (http://code.google.com/), but I'm not exactly sure how to formulate the search. The basic structure of the code would look something like this, but the names could be almost anything.

Answer (score 4):

You asked in the comments where to put the static helper, I suggest

```
public class All {
    public static final boolean notNull(Object... all) { ... }
}
```

and then use the qualified name for call, such as

```
assert All.notNull(a, b, c, d);
```

Same can then be done with a class `Any` and methods like `isNull`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 you can do it in even more elegant way:

```
if (Stream.of(a, b, c, d).anyMatch(Objects::isNull)) { ... }
```

or you can extract it to a method:

```
public static boolean anyNull(Object... objects) {
    return Stream.of(objects).anyMatch(Objects::isNull);
}
```

and then use it in your code like this:

```
if (anyNull(a, b, c, d)) { ... }
```